# Do I need to use iframes or is there a different method?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've been working on this project for a few days and I really haven't found any solid information, other than a co-worker saying I should use a iframe. Hopefully others could chime in and help me out.

**Problem:**

I have a index page with various links that once clicked will perform a slidedown and reveal content from another page (subpage). However, the subpage has a image rotator which works fine when you view it on it's own, but doesn't work when you view in the index page. The jQuery is not being called, so the image rotator dies. What would be the best method of allowing the content from the subpages to be viewed with it's rotator on the index page?

Sorry if this is confusing, I've worded it the best I could, but if anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it. I have no experience with jQuery and am a total novice. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: You could post the code you're having a problem with, and fix that problem. I think suggesting an `iframe` seems a little bit of cheap/bad advice. My guess is you just need to re-initialize the image rotator when you display it. Note, you should be (if you aren't) testing the page with Firebug or Chrome console open, to see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: Maybe if you show us your code so far.. =)

Comment: Can't post the code, but if one you guys be willing to hit me up with your email, I could send it to you?

Comment: That's going to prompt this question to be closed. I'm really of a mind that you're needing to initialize your rotator when you view that content (after the effect completes), or some other error is occurring. Without seeing the actual slidedown page code and what is displayed, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to load the proper JavaScript after the HTML for the "image rotator" is loaded into the DOM.

While you make the AJAX call for the "image rotator" use `$.getScript()` to get the include file for the "image rotator":

```
var XHRs = [];
XHRs.push($.get('<URL TO HTML>', function () {...}));
XHRs.push($.getScript('<URL TO JAVASCRIPT>', function () {...}));
$.when(XHRs).then(function () {
    //here is where you initialize the "image rotator" because the HTML and the JS will be loaded into the DOM
});
```

If you want to keep your "image rotator" initialization script external you can make another `$.getScript()` call inside the anonymous function in the `.then` function call.

Answer (score 0):

Look into jquery plugins like [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or [fancy box](http://fancbox.net).  They can do exactly what you want.